# MySQL date range pull using Python : TypeError:unhashable type: 'bytearray'

Tags: python-3.x, arrays, mysql-python, date-range

I am trying to figure out how to pull data from a table that has a column that is called 'sent_time' and the datetime falls between two datetimes. I was finally able to figure out how to use dateutil parser to be able to input the two dates for the date range pull. My problem now is that I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\timerange.py", line 75, in <module>
    worksheet.write(r,0,row[0])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 64, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 436, in write
    return self.write_string(row, col, *args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 64, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 470, in write_string
    string_index = self.str_table._get_shared_string_index(string)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\sharedstrings.py", line 128, in _get_shared_string_index
    if string not in self.string_table:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'
```

It's the bytearray that has got me puzzled. Could you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

---

I want to give you all the information I have with all the other files and what I'm shooting for to see if you can replicate and actually get it working just to see if it's not just my system or some configuration I have..

I have a database with one table.Lets call it ‘table1’ The table is broken down with columns like this:

sent_time | delivered_time |id1_active |id2_active |id3_active |id1_inactive |id2_inactive |id3_inactive |location_active |location_inactive …..`lots more

Lets say that these are two or more customers delivering goods to and from each other. Each customer has three id#s.

I created a ‘config.ini’ file to make my life a bit easier

```
[mysql]
host = localhost
database = db_name
user = root
password = blahblah
```

I created a ‘python_mysql_dbconfig.py’

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

def read_db_config(filename=’config.ini’, section=’mysql’):
“”” Read database configuration file and return a dictionary object
:param filename: name of the configuration file
:param section: section of database configuration
:return: a dictionary of database parameters
“””
# create parser and read ini configuration file
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read(filename)

# get section, default to mysql
db = {}
if parser.has_section(section):
items = parser.items(section)
for item in items:
db[item[0]] = item[1]
else:
raise Exception(‘{0} not found in the {1} file’.format(section, filename))

return db
```

---

This is the code that I'm working on right now...could you take a look?

```
# Establish a MySQL connection
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
db_config = read_db_config()
conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
cursor = conn.cursor(raw=True)

#to export to excel
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

#to get the csv converter functions
import os
import subprocess
import glob

#to get the datetime functions
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser

#creates the path needed for output files
path = 'C:/Python34/output_files/'

#creates the workbook
output_filename = input('output filename:')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path + output_filename + '.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

#formatting definitions
bold    = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'})
timeShape =  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

#actual query


query = (
    "SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, OBJ, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 "
    "WHERE sent_time BETWEEN %s AND %s"
)
userIn = dateutil.parser.parse(input('start date:'))
userEnd = dateutil.parser.parse(input('end date:'))


# Execute sql Query
cursor.execute(query,(userIn, userEnd))
result = cursor.fetchall()


#sets up the header row
worksheet.write('A1','sent_time',bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'delivered_time',bold)
worksheet.write('C1', 'customer_name',bold)
worksheet.write('D1', 'id1_active',bold)
worksheet.write('E1', 'id2_active',bold)
worksheet.write('F1', 'id3_active',bold)
worksheet.write('G1', 'id1_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('H1', 'id2_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('I1', 'id3_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('J1', 'location_active',bold)
worksheet.write('K1', 'location_inactive',bold)
worksheet.autofilter('A1:K1')  #dropdown menu created for filtering


#print into client to see that you have results
print("     sent_time     ", "        delivered_time     ", "OBJ", "\t   id1_active  ", "   id2_active  ", "    id3_active  ", "\t", " id1_inactive ", " id2_inactive ", "  id3_inactive ", "\tlocation_active", "\tlocation_inactive")
for row in result:
    print(*row, sep='\t')


# Create a For loop to iterate through each row in the XLS file, starting at row 2 to skip the headers
for r, row in enumerate(result, start=1):  #where you want to start printing results inside workbook
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,0,row[0], date_format)
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,1, row[1], date_format)
        worksheet.write(r,2, row[2])
        worksheet.write(r,3, row[3])
        worksheet.write(r,4, row[4])
        worksheet.write(r,5, row[5])
        worksheet.write(r,6, row[6])
        worksheet.write(r,7, row[7])
        worksheet.write(r,8, row[8])
        worksheet.write(r,9, row[9])
        worksheet.write(r,10, row[10])




#close out everything and save
cursor.close()
workbook.close()
conn.close()

#print number of rows and bye-bye message
print ("- - - - - - - - - - - - -")
rows = len(result)
print ("I just imported "+ str(rows) + " rows from MySQL!")
print ("")
print ("Good to Go!!!")
print ("")


#CONVERTS JUST CREATED FILE TO CSV

# set path to folder containing xlsx files

out_path ='C:/Python34/csv_files'
os.chdir(path)


# find the file with extension .xlsx
xlsx = glob.glob(output_filename + '.xlsx')

# create output filenames with extension .csv
csvs = [x.replace('.xlsx','.csv') for x in xlsx]

# zip into a list of tuples
in_out = zip(xlsx,csvs)

# loop through each file, calling the in2csv utility from subprocess
for xl,csv in in_out:
   out = open(csv,'w')
   command = 'c:/python34/scripts/in2csv %s\\%s' % (path,xl)
   proc = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=out)
   proc.wait()
   out.close()

print('XLSX and CSV files named ' + output_filename + ' were created')
```

Comment: There is way too much code and unrelated detail here. You need to look at the types in these arguments - `worksheet.write(r,0,row[0])` . and find out why the db driver is mapping something from your table to bytearray rather than string (if that's what actually happening)

Comment: I gave all my code to see if someone wants to replicate what I'm doing to see what i'm doing wrong. I know what is setting my code off is the userIn and UserEnd inputs that i used dateutil.parser.parse on. I am trying to figure out how to convert it back to string at the worksheet.write(r,0,row[0])

Comment: if you want someone to replicate the problem, you do this not dump all your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  But you should be looking into why you are getting a bytearray rather than a string in the first place. The column types in mysql might have something to do with it.

Comment: thanks i'll do that next time.

Comment: the column type for the columns being looked at (sent_timet,delivered_time) are both datetime types. That is why I was using the util parser to have the dates to query be input variables. When I did that, it changed the types for row[0] and row[1].

Comment: I guess you don't yet know where in this set of arguments the bytearray is, right? Have you tried dumping out the whole thing along with the type info?

Comment: No..I'm relatively new...I'm just doing this to work with my gps and learning as I go..I can't just do textbook. i learn thru examples.

Comment: Put a `print(map(type, result[0]))` right before '#print into client to see that you have results' and see what it spits out.

Comment: cool! it spat out <map object at 0x00000000043FFC18>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98733/discussion-between-daniel-and-pvg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've disabled type conversion in `cursor = conn.cursor(raw=True)`. Remove the `raw=True` so the driver stops giving you straight bytearrays for all types.